# Installing alternative perl version - module missing

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I have a webapp which uses an older version of Perl. I therefore installed an independent Perl version using perlbrew, made a symlink /usr/bin/perlx and changed the path in all my perl files.
However, I still have some problems with the additional modules that I've installed. If I try to start the webapp, I get an error message:

> Can't locate JSON/XS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/x86_64-linux /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1 /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/x86_64-linux /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1 .) at ism/readfn.pm line 42.

According to `cpan -i JSON::XS`, the module is installed:

> JSON::XS is up to date (2.33)

However, `find /opt/ -name 'XS.pm'` only prints other locations:

> /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/x86_64-linux/List/Util/XS.pm
>   /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/ExtUtils/Constant/XS.pm
>   /opt/perlbrew/build/perl-5.10.1/ext/List-Util/lib/List/Util/XS.pm
>   /opt/perlbrew/build/perl-5.10.1/lib/List/Util/XS.pm
>   /opt/perlbrew/build/perl-5.10.1/lib/ExtUtils/Constant/XS.pm
>   /opt/perlbrew/build/perl-5.10.1/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/XS.pm

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if your `cpan` is working with the same `perl` as the one that says that you don't have `JSON::XS` installed:

```
which perl
which cpan
```

Comment: I've started cpan directly from the perlbrew version: /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/cpan

Comment: Did you fix this problem? If Tudor's suggestion shows that the correct Perl is being referenced, try removing the shebang line from your .pl file(s), and executing it: "perl example.pl"

Comment: Well, this took some time... 
I've installed a second cpan using `/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/cpan App::cpanminus`, however, I simply forgot to switch the Perl version!